# 403 Forbidden when trying to access static files on elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have successfully deployed my application to Elastic beanstalk.  Everything is working except the bootstrap themes.  When I view source and try to access the links to the files I get.

Source

```
<!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href= "/static/css/blog-home.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href= "/static/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

I get this...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /static/bootstrap.min.css
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

Here is what I see in my logs

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 18657] [client 10.30.229.177:34675] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /webapp, referer: http://www.evenster.io/user/user_id=2
```

I have configured the properties on EB to include the static folders in python.conf

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```

I have also done a chmod -R 777 on my entire application tree to ensure that the files have permision.

My folder structure is:

```
app
├── __init__py.old
├── application.py
├── application.pyc
├── manage.py
├── migrations
│   ├── README
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── env.pyc
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
│       ├── 48f38b800968_.py
│       └── 48f38b800968_.pyc
├── requirements.txt
└── webapp
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── _olddatabase.db
    ├── config.py
    ├── config.pyc
    ├── database.db
    ├── forms.py
    ├── forms.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── static
    │   ├── blog-home.css
    │   ├── bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
    │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
    │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── blog-home.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
    │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
    │   │   ├── toolkit.css
    │   │   └── toolkit.min.css
    │   ├── fonts
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    │   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
    │   └── js
    │       ├── bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
    │       ├── bootstrap.js
    │       ├── bootstrap.min.js
    │       ├── jquery.js
    │       ├── moment-with-locales.min.js
    │       ├── moment.js
    │       ├── npm.js
    │       ├── scripts.js
    │       ├── toolkit.js
    │       └── toolkit.min.js
    ├── templates
    │   ├── 500.html
    │   ├── _login.html
    │   ├── _question_settings.html
    │   ├── base.html
    │   ├── create_event.html
    │   ├── create_event2.html
    │   ├── create_user.html
    │   ├── event.html
    │   ├── events.html
    │   ├── flash.html
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── index2.html
    │   ├── login.html
    │   ├── logout.html
    │   ├── question.html
    │   ├── questions.html
    │   ├── test.html
    │   ├── user.html
    │   ├── user_events.html
    │   ├── user_questions.html
    │   └── users.html
    ├── views.py
    └── views.pyc
```